# Math not coming up right in NSInteger Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsinteger

So I've got a basic math equation I'm trying to perform in programming.

```
NSInteger testValue = (self.waveform.zoomStartSamples/self.waveform.totalSamples)*100;
```

Self.waveform.zoomStartSamples is @property (nonatomic, assign) unsigned long int zoomStartSamples;

self.waveform.totalSamples is @property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) unsigned long int totalSamples;

Here are the NSLog's I'm running

```
    NSLog(@"Value of testValue is %ld", (long)testValue);
    NSLog(@"zoomStartSamples are %lu", self.waveform.zoomStartSamples);
    NSLog(@"totalSamples are %lu", self.waveform.totalSamples);
```

And here is the result I get:

Value of testValue is 0
zoomStartSamples are 1033554
totalSamples are 4447232

I don't think the value of testValue should be coming up 0. Any ideas?

Ultimately I would like to float the value to another variable to use it elsewhere. Thanks.

Comment: You think wrong.  You're doing integer arithmetic.  1033554 divided by 4447232 is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `zoomStartSamples/totalSamples` results in a int 0, so 0*100 = 0, try to use 
`zoomStartSamples * 100/totalSamples` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is the nature of integer math. 1033554 / 4447232 = 0.23240388628252. However, that value can't be represented as an integer. It's between 0 and 1. In C, the result is truncated to 0. Then, you multiply that by 100, which still yields 0.

If you want fractional values, you need to use floating-point math. You can convert the result back to an integer at the end. In many cases, the compiler will do that final conversion automatically. For example:

```
NSInteger testValue = (self.waveform.zoomStartSamples/(double)self.waveform.totalSamples)*100;
```

By casting one subexpression to `double`, the division is performed with `double`s. The numerator is automatically promoted to `double`. The result is a `double`. Similarly, the multiplication is performed with `double`s; the `100` is promoted to a `double`. When the `double` result is assigned to an integer variable, it is truncated.